# Mono doesn't recognize SHA1 as hash algorithm for RSA signing

Tags: c#, mono, .net-3.5, cryptography, sha1

I am trying to port some code from C# to Mono for a future Linux project.

Mono outputs this error:

> `A System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographyException was thrown; sha1 is an unsupported hash algorithm for RSA signing"`

when running or debugging this code for RSA signing:

```
byte[] bytesSing = rsa.SignHash(hashValue, "SHA1");
```

I checked with VS2010 and the reference says it must be a string, which I passed as "SHA1". This compiled and ran under Windows, but does not compile or run under Mono.

Here's Mono's [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/RSACryptoServiceProvider.cs#L-311).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the source code file you linked, the `SignHash` function assumes that the string you're passing is an OID, and tries to look it up as such in the `GetHashNameFromOID` function directly above it.

The [Mono documentation](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aSystem.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.SignHash) supports this, documenting that parameter as:

> The hash algorithm identifier (OID) used to create the hash value of the data.

The [Microsoft implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/rsacryptoserviceprovider.cs,5f1fa01e73f14ef5) looks the parameter up through `X509Utils.NameOrOidToAlg`, which probably accepts either a name or an OID.

So to get it working, you should be able to pass `null` in the Mono version, or pass the OID "1.3.14.3.2.26".

Comment: Many Thanks pmcoltrane! it works flawlessly now!

(How do i close this thread?)

Comment: @Glas You don't. Questions only get closed if they're not welcome on the site. Just accept the answer you like best. Perhaps somebody else comes a long and posts another answer.